# Timer Speed is increasing on picker selection change

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a timer which is working on a picker selection changed.Timer is working good until the times end to the "00:00:00".If i change the selection changed in the mid of time then the speed of timer is increased and if i again change selected index than timer run much fast. My problem is that timer should run on 1 sec dealy every time.
I am sharing my code below. Thanks in advance for help.

//picker selection change

```
           private async void GName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                   
            lblEndTime.Text = "00:00:10";
     
            StartTimmer();
      
            }

         public void StartTimmer()
          {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
          {
              TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(lblEndTime.Text);

              timeSpan -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

              if (lblEndTime.Text == "00:00:00")
              {
                  returnValue = false;

              }
              else
              {
                  lblEndTime.Text = Convert.ToString(timeSpan);

              }

          });

            return returnValue;
        });
     }
```

Comment: every time your picker changes you are creating a new timer instance, and you end up with multiple timers fighting each other.  You should also use System.Timers instead of Device.StartTimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [System.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1) and stop the timer every time you change the selected index instead of creating a new one.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    Timer Timer1 { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void StartTimmer()
    {
        if (Timer1 != null)
        {
            Timer1.Stop();
            Timer1.Dispose();
        }

        Timer1 = new Timer();
        Timer1.Interval = 1000;
        Timer1.Enabled = true;

        Timer1.Start();


        Timer1.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(lblEndTime.Text);

                timeSpan -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

                if (lblEndTime.Text == "00:00:00")
                {
                    Timer1.Stop();
                    Timer1.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblEndTime.Text = Convert.ToString(timeSpan);
                }

            });          
        };

    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblEndTime.Text = "00:00:10";

        StartTimmer();
    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label x:Name="lblEndTime" Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Button_Clicked"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    
</StackLayout>
```